# How can I check if image isDirty PhotoEditorSDK

Tags: javascript, css, html, photoeditorsdk

I'm trying to prompt a modal that asks to save the image when you click the close button in the Desktop UI.

I want to check if the image the image is changed since the last Export. How can I check if the image has been edited and is currently "dirty" ?

Comment: did you ever find a workaround for this isDirty feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no proper way todo this right now. However, we just added a new feature which will be available with the next minor release.

Comment: was this 'isDirty' option ever released in the latter release- if so can someone point me in the direction?